# how to create a curved border for a label in extjs?

Tags: extjs4, extjs4.1

I am trying to create a curved border(border line with curved corner) for a label in extjs. this is for highlighting some important text?

```
 xtype: label,
 text: 'my text',
 margin: '0 0 0 5'
```

these are my current properties of that label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way of doing it is by using css.

The css file:

```
.round-corners {
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -o-border-radius: 3px;
    -ms-border-radius: 3px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
```

And then:

```
xtype: label,
text: 'my text',
margin: '0 0 0 5',
cls: 'round-corners',
```

Comment: getting a validation error like. css 2.1 validation: 'border-radius' is not a known property name

Comment: Yes. Round corners are only supported with modern browsers. You'll have to fall back to round corner images for legacy browsers.

Comment: By the way, [ext-all.css](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/resources/css/ext-all.css) will also fail validation.